# ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. after put \centering into my code

Tags: tables, errors

I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

when I'm using `\centering` in my code below. Without `\centering` it works but the table is not centered. Hope you can help me!

```
\documentclass{statsoc}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{}
\label{}
\fbox{%
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
Cox-Model & Correct Model & Bias 1 & Bias 2\\
\hline
Basic & 1.133  & 1.302  & 1.124 \\
Strata(country) & 1.062 & 1.293 & 1.062 \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

the statsoc.cls-file is very large!
you can get it here by downloading 'RSS style guide':
[enter link description here](http://www.rss.org.uk/RSS/Publications/Journals/Journals_get_involved/RSS/Publications/Journals_sub/Get_Involved.aspx?hkey=c0e4b249-4847-4666-bc92-66b4e8c11199)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By simply wrapping a document around your code snipped, it works fine for me. Please show a small compilable document that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added the .cls-file to the question. thx!!

Comment: Did you test that your MWE reproduces the error? Looks like a few things are missing....

Answer (score 1):

Use `\centering` only after the caption:

```
\caption{}
\label{}
\centering
```